# Shared device with WebAuthN and platform authenticator

Tags: authentication, webauthn, fido

We have a scenario where some of our B2B customers use shared ipads at their sites/locations i.e. a single ipad is shared between multiple users.

Can we still authenticate using WebAuthN with platform authenticator for this scenario? I'm trying to validate whether WebAuthN will be viable for our scenario as one of the key requirements is for auth to be "frictionless".

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you can leverage cross-device authentication features so that such customers use their own device (BYOD) with hybrid transport.
Creating the platform authenticator (passkey) on the shared device does not recommended.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).